# implement a tag solution where users can submit there own tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, controller, tags, modeling

Im have been looking for a gem to support a solid tags feature for an app but havent found anything satisfying. it doesent have to be overly complex lean and mean is better. 
Now investigating the options to create my own tag model controller and solution.

Has anyone created a tags solution and what would be a good way to do it?
Also I would like to have the option for users to submit there own tags so the "Tag base" can grow with input from many users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a MongoDB this might point you in the right direction. With the gem I posted below, tags can be created with objects and available for querying. More elaborate code would be required but it might get you started:

https://github.com/mauriciozaffari/mongoid_search

Comment: Thx for the suggestion, i havent thought of using mongodb for this, while it might be a far  better fix than mysql to store the data.

Comment: Investigating in this direction, not full solution but a place to start